# How to implement, exit from the app should occur only on double click on any of three buttons given in android phones?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

A famous game pubg just implemented a new feature in android game app,
If we double tap on either overview button, home button or back button then only it responses,

As i know, generally double tap/click on back button stops the running app, but only single tap on home or overview button lands to home screen or minimises the app.

I need the same in my app, User will have to double tap on overview, home or exit button for the result, like if user wants to go on home screen then User have to double tap on home button.

Comment: Maybe you can measure the duration between two consecutive taps. If the duration is below a threshold ( like 300ms ), then the action will be performed.

Comment: yeah right! but before that  we have a method onBackPressed() in android  to track whether back button clicked, does such method exist that can track overview or home button too, that i need to know?

Answer (score 0):

first of all, using a double click is not recommended in android studio, you have the long click option which is much must better, [here is how to implement it!](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLongClickListener).

if your long click is already take by some other feature or you just really want the double click you have few options:

1) add a [Gesture Listener](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-introduction-to-gestures--mobile-2239).

2) By using a boolean to detect the double click as follows:

- Add a boolean `du_click = false;` and a `Handler du_handler;`
- when the btn is click check the `du_click` if it `false` or `true`.
- if it's `true` it means it is a double click
- if it's `false` it means it's not a double click so set `du_click` to `true`.
- use your handler `postDelayed()` method to set it back to `false` after some period of time(i.e 1 second).

if you're having a lot of trouble with the `Handler` you can also accomplish it by after the first click set a timer to count for a period of time(i.e 1 second) using a thread and after it to check if there was another click(via the `boolean du_click`) but I think the `Handler` is your best option(or using the `Gesture Listener`).